# Comparing tables that do not have same number of rows but same number of columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables for instance Table `A` and Table `B`.

Table `A` and `B` has same number of columns, but table `A` has few extra rows.

I was wondering if there's a query that would compare Table `A` and `B` and delete the extra number of rows that exist in Table `A`.

And also it would be good to have a temp table that would the values that were deleted. A

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
[Edited]

```
Delete from A where id in 
             (
                Select id from ((select id from A) minus (select id from B))
             );
```

Above query assumes that A and B have same columns which includes an id column [which is unique].

Comment: This script seems to delete the rows that are same in table A and B. I want to delete the rows that are not same. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: @spaniard89: Why do think so? I am getting difference of 2 tables and then removing the from A which is what you want.

Comment: Hi lokesh, I want to delete all the rows from table A which is not present in table B. But the script above finds the difference and deletes all the rows from A. I am kinda new to SQL, i would appreciate any help mate.

Comment: @spaniard89: Try the new query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tableA a left join TableB b on a.id = b.id
```

will give the difference in table data. You can play with the `null` value to delete the extra data in `tableA`